# Кириллица в регулярном выражении JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Данный код переводит в верхний регистр первых букв слова, но почему то не работает с кириллицей

Допустим: ivanov иван, вывод: Ivanov иван

```js
function foobar(str) { 
    return str.replace(/\b(.)/g, 
        function(s) {
            return s.toUpperCase(); 
        } 
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` не понимает кирилицу,

```
function foobar(str) { 
    return str.replace(/(^(.)|\s(.))/g, 
        function(s) {
            return s.toUpperCase(); 
        } 
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Или `this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1)`. :)